# How to determine if the first character of a NSString is a letter

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

In my app

i need to know if the **first character** of a string is a letter or not

Im getting first character of the string like this

```
NSString *codeString;
 NSString *firstLetter = [codeString substringFromIndex:1];
```

I can know it by comparing with a, b, c, .**.

```
if([firstLetter isEqualToString "a"] || ([firstLetter isEqualToString "A"] || ([firstLetter isEqualToString "b"] ......)
```

But is there any other method to know?

I need to display different colors for letters and symbols.

How can i achieve it in simple way?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

First off, your line:

```
NSString *firstLetter = [codeString substringFromIndex:1];
```

does not get the first letter. This gives you a new string the contains all of the original string EXCEPT the first character. This is the opposite of what you want. You want:

```
NSString *firstLetter = [codeString substringToIndex:1];
```

But there is a better way to see if the first character is a letter or not.

```
unichar firstChar = [[codeString uppercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];
if (firstChar >= 'A' && firstChar <= 'Z') {
    // The first character is a letter from A-Z or a-z
}
```

However, since iOS apps deal with international users, it is far from ideal to simply look for the character being in the letters A-Z. A better approach would be:

```
unichar firstChar = [codeString characterAtIndex:0];
NSCharacterSet *letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
if ([letters characterIsMember:firstChar]) {
    // The first character is a letter in some alphabet
}
```

There are a few cases where this doesn't work as expected. `unichar` only holds 16-bit characters. But `NSString` values can actually have some 32-bit characters in them. Examples include many Emoji characters. So it's possible this code can give a false positive. Ideally you would want to do this:

```
NSRange first = [codeString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0];
NSRange match = [codeString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] options:0 range:first];
if (match.location != NSNotFound) {
    // codeString starts with a letter
}
```