# BOOL method for returning UITextView input not executing or attributing strings

Tags: objective-c, methods, uitextview, nsattributedstring

The objective of the program is to change the color of words with the same first letter **as the user inputs text to the** `UITextView` **called** `lyricsTxtView`. It works sort of like an Xcode editor where data types, for example, immediately turn pink when typed.

My implementation code has a BOOL method for detecting text input. I tried to describe chunks of code with comments to help understand my process:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *lyricsTxtView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

 //check for text view input
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView*)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{


     //create string textViewText with text view text
    NSString *textViewText = [_lyricsTxtView text];
    NSLog(@"UITextView text: %@", textViewText);

     //create mutable attributed string with string textViewText
    NSMutableAttributedString *textViewTextMut =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: textViewText];
    NSLog(@"UITextView attributable text: %@", textViewTextMut);

    //create array of words by separating string textViewText by spaces
    NSArray *words = [textViewText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"word array: %@", words);

    /*NOW WE HAVE ESTABLISHED THE UITEXTVIEW TEXT IN ATTRIBUTABLE FORM AND AN ARRAY OF WORDS TO START ANAYLYZING LETTERS*/

    //declare mutable array for first letters
    NSMutableArray *letters1;

    //add first letters of each word in array words to array letters1
    for (NSString *word in words) {
       if ([word length] > 0){
          NSString *firstLetter = [word substringToIndex:1];
          [letters1 addObject: firstLetter];
    }
       else {
          continue;
       }

    }
    NSLog(@"first array of first letters: %@", letters1);

    //create array letters2 matching letters1
    NSArray *letters2 = letters1;
    NSLog(@"second array of first letters: %@", letters2);

    /*NOW WE ALSO HAVE TWO ARRAYS OF EVERY WORDS' FIRST LETTER, SO WE CAN START COMPARING LETTERS*/

    //compare all letters in letters1 with all letters in letters2
    for (NSString *letter1 in letters1) {
        for (NSString *letter2 in letters2) {

    //check for matching letters
            if ([letter1 isEqualToString:letter2]) {

    //check if letters have the same index, and...
                NSUInteger letter1Index = [letters1 indexOfObject:letter1];
                NSUInteger letter2Index = [letters2 indexOfObject:letter2];

    //if they don't, get the index of string word in array words who's index matches the index of string letter1 in array letters1 and the string word in array words who's index matches the index of string letter2 in array letters2. store them in an array. but...
                NSMutableArray *matchWords;
                if (letter1Index != letter2Index) {
                    for (NSString *word in words) {
                        if ([word isEqual:words[letter1Index]] ||
                            [word isEqual:words[letter2Index]]) {

                            [matchWords addObject: word];
                            NSLog(@"array of matching words: %@", matchWords);

    //attribute word within nested loops, which will account for all words with the matching letter.
                            NSRange range=[textViewText rangeOfString:word];

                            [textViewTextMut addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];
                        }

                    }

                }

    //if they do, do nothing because we are comparing a word's first letter with itself.
                else {
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }

    /*WE HAVE CHOSEN TO DO NOTHING WHEN MATCHING LETTERS TURN OUT TO BE ANALYZED ON THE SAME WORD. WHEN THEY ARE FOUND TO BE MATCHING LETTERS IN SEPARATE WORDS, THE WORDS ARE ATTRIBUTED.*/
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_lyricsTxtView setDelegate:self];
}
```

The code above has no warnings or errors, so I am having trouble determining if my issue lies in the method declaration or my way of attributing (coloring) words.

Comment: `NSString *firstLetter = [word substringFromIndex:1];` doesn't get the first letter of the word; it gets everything *except* the first letter.  You want `substringToIndex` instead.

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through the code line by line and look at the value of each variable and see if it is what you expected.

Comment: @NobodyNada thank you, I have edited my code.

Comment: @rmaddy I am not getting my first NSLog(@"UITextView text: %@", textViewText), and the debugger only shows responses when I first click into the UITextView then when I begin typing. Nothing else. Therefore, I would think the method isn't being called at all.

Comment: Did you set the delegate of your textView?

Comment: @NobodyNada Actually, using `substringToIndex:1` doesn't always get the 1st letter either. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16860279/1226963

Comment: @user3884788 None of the code you posted has any calls to `NSLog` so that doesn't help us. And if the `shouldChangeTextInRange:` method you posted isn't being called then you probably didn't set the text view's `delegate`.

Comment: @NobodyNada @rmaddy @user3884788 my code is updated with all `NSLogs` and the text view delegate set. The app now crashes, and the error now relates to finding the first letters incorrectly: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringToIndex:]: Index 1 out of bounds; string length 0'`

Comment: Stop trying to do everything in one method. Break the problem up into several smaller problems that you can implement and test independently. For example a function that takes two words and returns true/false depending on whether their first letters match. Start small and work your way up.

Comment: @DanielT. I separated the functions into methods, but it kept printing the same NSLog, so right now it is one method until I sort it out. I'm so close. The debugger reads: `2016-10-02 00:55:54.669 Rap Edit[7365:1168554] word array: (
    Type,
    your,
    typilyrics,
    "here.",
    ""
)
2016-10-02 00:55:54.669 Rap Edit[7365:1168554] first array of first letters: (null)
2016-10-02 00:55:54.669 Rap Edit[7365:1168554] second array of first letters: (null)`

Comment: which is significant because now I know that the array of words isn't being formed correctly and that the arrays of letters aren't being formed at all.

Comment: Good, now write a function that takes a string and returns an array of words. Test it using unit tests. Start by passing it a single word, then two words, then add punctuation... Break your complex problem into a bunch of simpler problems.